# Instantiate a map object given an instance of a <div> HTML element

Tags: javascript, leaflet

The [leaflet docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-example) say a map can be created by:

> `L.map(<HTMLElement> el, <Map options> options?)`
>
> Instantiates a map object given an instance of a  HTML element
> and optionally an object literal with Map options.

What does this look like?

I'm new to Javascript and, although I've read through much of [MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript), I'm clearly missing something.  I'm trying things like,

```html
<script>
    var mydiv = document.createElement("div");
    L.map(mydiv);
</script>
```

My understanding is that we'd be using JS to create a new tag element which would be inserted into the page.  Then `L.map()` would use that object reference, rather than a `<div>` id.

Comment: you're on the right lines... what's your actual problem?

Comment: You've created a `HTMLDivElement`, but it's not part of the [DOM tree](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model). You might want to do something along the lines of `document.body.appendChild(mydiv)` (and also give it a non-zero size, i.e. `mydiv.style.height='100px';`)

Comment: you've created the `div` but haven't inserted it into the page. You can insert it with `document.body.append(mydiv)`

Comment: @IvanSanchez if you'd like to copy the answer I just posted, I can delete mine and accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is correct but you need to add the DIV to the DOM.

Another probably easier way to do it, if it's valid for your usecase, is to create a div in your HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id='map'></div>
</body>
```

And then create your map in that DIV, instead of having to append it to the DOM:

```
<script>
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("map");
    L.map(mydiv);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of instantiating a map object given an instance of an HTML element:

```js
var mydiv = document.createElement("div");  // create <div> element
mydiv.style.height='100px';                 // give the div a fixed height per leaflet recommendations
document.body.appendChild(mydiv);           // add the new element to the DOM (could also use .append())
L.map(mydiv);                               // instantiate a map using an HTML element instance
```